# Range.Value = "" type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some code to format a series of worksheets into a standardized format. To do this, I want to remove blank rows, delete leading spaces, and remove ";*" that start a lot of lines. Upon trying to see if aRow.Value = "", meaning there is no text in the row, a type mismatch error is always returned.

I have tried many different solutions from the internet, but none seem to work.

```
Sub Format()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aRow As Range
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim cel As String

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each aRow In ws.UsedRange.Rows
            If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If aRow.Value = "" Then
                aRow.Delete
            End If
            If aRow.Value = " " Then
                aRow.Delete
            End If
            If Left(aRow.Value2, 2) = ";*" Then
                aRow.Value = Right(aRow.Value2, Len(aRow.Value2) - 2)
            Else
                aRow.Delete
            End If
            cel = "A" & aRow.Row
            aRow.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range(cel).Value)
            If aRow.Value = Empty Then
                aRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your third `If` statement checks if cell value starts with `;*` IF not, it will delete the row. So actually, you are deleting **all** rows (including those with `""`and `" "`), except those where first cell in column starts with `;*`. In that case, you don't need the first two ifs.

Answer (score 1):

Row represents an entire row in Excel and not a cell. 
You can not assigning a string value ("") to a row.

In your case, you want to check if the first cell equals to some value.
Instead of checking `aRow.Value=` use `aRow.Cells(1).Value`.

Once you detected the row to delete, use `aRow.Clear()` to clear all row content.

Comment: All the data I am trying to format is in the first column. Does that mean I should reference that specific cell instead of using aRow throughout my code?

Comment: Yes. If you know the cell, use cell.Clear(). Cell value can have different types (number, string) so calling a Clear() function should be safer. It also removes the formating.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Where are you suggesting I put the cell.clear function?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. I think you could replace line

`For Each aRow In ws.UsedRange.Rows`

by this:

```
For Each aRow In ws.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
```

That way, you will loop trough each cell of first column.

To delete an entire row, then you could use `aRow.EntireRow.Delete`

Hope this helps

Comment: When I try to do that replacement, I get an error that says "Object doesn't support this property or method" Any idea why?

Comment: It works for me perfectly, so maybe you are using it in the wrong place. How is your code now? Can you update your question with new code?

Comment: I just had a typo, but now the aRow.EntireRow.Delete statement is giving me an error. Method 'Delete' of object 'Range' failed

Comment: `aRow.EntireRow.Delete` works too perfectly for me. How does your code looks now? Maybe it could be that you already deleted that row and then it fails because it is still associated to a non real range because the structure of your code. Debug it. Execute it with F8 step by step what is happening.